# Acessing Weights of LSTM Cell in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm

How do i get the weights of an LSTM Cell. I would like to assign the weights of this to another LSTM Cell in another network, i.e copy contents.

If this was normal weights, i would do sess.run(w1.assign(w2),..)

Comment: Could you paste in what you have so far? Consider reading this and revising your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using [tf.get_variable](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a0d784bdd31b27e013a7eac58a86ba62e86db299/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard9/tf.get_variable.md) function. 
All you need is the names of those variables.

You can get them by running something like this:

```
for v in tf.global_variables():
    print(v.name)
```